# How to load email signature automatically?

Tags: windows, email, windows-live-mail, email-signature

I have a signature set up in my client e-mail (Windows Live Mail) which is an image, because it uses a lot of styles.

When I send email it to another person, their e-mail client asks them whether they want to load my signature image.

Is there a way to have the recipient's email client load my image automatically?

Comment: No, they're settings won't allow pictures to load unless they set them to. Try a text-only signature.

Comment: Set an [alt value of the image](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_img_alt.asp) if you must perpetrate this insanity of having an image-based signature.

Comment: @Zoredache I already do that, but the question is about the image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No there isn't. It's entirely up to the person receiving the email to decide whether or not to show/download any images included in an email.

It's a good thing both for privacy<sup>*****</sup> and conserving bandwidth.

<sup>*****</sup><sup>If image loading could be forced an unscrupulous person could embed an unique one-pixel-image in each email and thus know if and when the email was read (and if the email address was valid)</sup>